# How do I search for links in Azure DevOps Wiki?

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-wiki

I am working on a POC for a new step in our CI pipeline.
The idea is to detect links in our Wiki that point to the code, so that when a file is changed in a pull request, if that file is referenced in a wiki page then a comment is posted on the PR saying "make sure you update [wiki page]".

I've been using the [DevOps Wiki Search Results REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/search/wiki-search-results/fetch-wiki-search-results?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) trying to detect the name of a code file, but it seems that the search API only searches in the page's text and that does not include links.

To illustrate, in the following markdown, `myClass` is found but `myClass.cs` is not.

```
# Section
This is a section about a topic.\
This is implemented in code in the [myClass](https://link-to-code.com/myClass.cs) class.
```

Does anyone know how to include the whole markdown in the search? Or if there is another way to access Azure wiki that allows this? Ideally we shouldn't have to explicitely mention the file name in the wiki text.

Comment: I'd like to add, technically I could always include the file name in the text of the link like `[file-name.cs](https://address.com/file-name.cs)`, but it would include all code files with that name (in a big solution, there can be many files with the same name).
And then get the markdown for the pages found using [GET pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages/get-page?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) to actually see the link and make sure it's the right file. However this could add quite some time to the pipeline. And it feels kinda botched.

Comment: Another thought is that you could create a clone of the Wiki's underlying git repository for your CI Pipeline to operate against, e.g. recurse the content and string search, [RegEx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), [unified](https://github.com/unifiedjs/collective#teams)/[remark](https://remark.js.org/) or the like. Not real clean but it may be another option. I'd like to hear whether/how you achieve this.